# How to configure VLANs with windows server 2016 DHCP in one VLAN

Tags: vlan, dhcp, topology

Here is an example of the network topology I am trying to create.
[image: VLAN Topology]

There is the standard router - Netgear Genie. It can link each port to a VLAN, and the Wifi can be on the vlan, but my thought was to leave this agnostic of VLAN and just route traffic. It is also a DHCP - ideally just for the Guest network.

The switch is a smart switch and supports VLAN,

There are two WAPS which are HP and can also broadcast multiple SSID each on a VLAN.

In the "Company" network, there is a Windows Server 2016, which is the AD, DNS, DHCP etc for the company network. (Company - small business from home...)

The "Guest" network would be for non business users who do not need access to the Company network and should not be able to see.

(There is also CCTV, and this would be useful to segment on it's own VLAN too. but this is an issue for another day)

I have two questions:

1) Is is possible to have the DHCP server on the router level, or does it need to reside within VLAN 101. (so they are both separate to each other)

2) What VLAN tagging and PVID settings are required for the switch.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be difficult with a consumer-grade router (off-topic here) because most do not support VLANs and the DHCP relays that you must configure.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The DHCP server can reside on the router, provide this router support settings a DHCP server for multiple networks. (Note that Netgear Genie is a home product and as such is off-topic here).

Alternatively, a single DHCP server located in a specific VLAN can serve multiple VLAN, using `DHCP relay` on the router that connect those VLAN, and settings the DHCP server IP address as the destination of the DHCP requests.

Since the Windows server is already in VLAN 102, it will directly server this VLAN and you only need to relay DHCP requests for VLAN 101.

On the switch, the ports that connect to hosts (computers, servers) must be set as `access` for the desired VLAN.

I.E. the port that connect the Windows server must be configured with PVID 102 and untagged VLAN 102.

Comment: Hello. thanks for the response. The router is a D6400, which claims to support VLAN, but not convinced it does it properly. The DHCP settings do not seem to apply to any particular network. Not sure it would support DHCP relay either.

Comment: Since you have already a windows DHCP server in VLAN 102 and need only one other DHCP server for VLAN 101 you could try to set the router DHCP server for this VLAN, without the need for DHCP relay.  Actually having a quick look at the user guide, the VLAN support is far from standard.

Comment: Would you be able to recommend the Tagging settings, and PVID required for this setup in the above diagram? Would be good to know I've at least got that right! I will have to recommend a replacement router to handle dhcp requests per vlan...

Comment: This router was the issue. Changed to a Draytek one and can setup a DHCP server per LAN so the SBS can do one, and the other guests DHCP by the router.